# Java/IntelliJ - Unknown class: 'JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jframe

I'm in the process of trying to learn Java. I feel it's one of the most relevant languages and I'd rather make the investment now to get myself the knowledge rather than do it later. I've sat down and looked at several Oracle docs on creating JFrame instances, but for whatever reason, I keep getting the error 'Unknown class'.

The syntax is different enough from what I've worked in so far that I don't know exactly what's going on. I tried making sure I placed an import directive for javax.swing.JFrame up into the top of the file, but the code still doesn't like what I'm trying to do.

Anyway, here goes the code. Please go easy on me, even though I'm well-experienced in programming in general, I have no idea about Java. This is a first for me.

```
package com.firstFrameApp.helloworld;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class helloWorld
{
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    JFrame frame0 = new Jframe("Hello World Example");

    frame0.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a class named `Jframe`, or is this a spelling mistake? (`JFrame` vs `Jframe`)?

Comment: Well spotted, Jesper.

Comment: Now I feel like an idiot. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no such class with name `Jframe` in imported packages.

Try this:

```
JFrame("Hello World Example");
```

To answer your comment: No, you do not have to create class named "JFrame". The main issue is: You are writing code, where class and instance variables can be declared. You should write code in method; something like this:

```
package com.firstFrameApp.helloworld;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class helloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        JFrame frame0 = new JFrame("Hello World Example");

        frame0.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it still carries an error. Do I need to create a class file called 'JFrame' and import it, even though I have the `import javax.swing.JFrame` directive specified?